# database regarding cars - for mysql

Tags: mysql, database

i have a dilema regarding my database design for my car system (my dad own a dealership and i want to build him a new system where the user can schedule test drives, apptointmen etc...)

i am undecide between these 2 models:

```
table car
 id int, model_id int, make_id int, price float, year year, millage int, etc...
```

or

```
table car
 id int, model enum, make enum, price float, year year, millage intetc...
```

**customer** table with (id int, name varchar, phone int, street varchar, city etc...

**salemen** table with (id int, name varchar,  etc...

**schedule** table (id int, appt_Date datetime, car_id, customer_id, salemen_id)

now my question is this:

should I use enum fields or should i have a table for each enum fields? i dont want to redesign the system once it is use by everyone and start all over again.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would stay away from ENUMs for one main reason. If you want to add new items, you have to ALTER the table. Which can be painful if you have tons of data. Also, depending the collation and the character set you use, you have be careful with case sensitivity.

Read this article for more info: [8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/).

Now using a reference data/table using a foreign key is preferable because you can have a data integrity rule. You can build a simple tool to manage these data (make or model) without altering or changing any database schema.

Answer (score 4):

my preference would be the first option.  use int as foreign key to the appropriate other tables.  this way, you add rows to those other tables, and the 'enum' values are automatically present.

you may want to post your proposed tables at some point to get some normalization help in general :)

Answer (score 4):

I've never used enum fields.

More than likely, you will be building an application on top of this, using a tool like PHP.  You CAN get the values out of the DB via a method like documented at http://barrenfrozenwasteland.com/?q=node/7

This is just a little more awkward than getting the possible values out of a separate table.

You will have a little more flexibility with a separate table, since you don't need to give the web user privileges to update the table definition itself.  There also appears to be a limit of 10,000ish distinct values in an enum field.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ENUM`.

Why? [**8 reasons.**](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)

Comment: Yeah, I hope it serves you well.. Got me to forget about enums, that article.. :D